# .htaccess RewriteRule to redirect http to https messes up % escaped parameters in URL

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, https

I'm using something similar to the following in my `.htaccess` file to redirect all `http` requests to `https`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

That works, except for a situation when a URL is passed with escaped parameters, as such:

```
http://www.example.com/download.php?go=app%20name
```

when redirected, it is mistakenly escaped again into:

```
https://www.example.com/download.php?go=app%2520name
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`NE` or `noescape` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) in your rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing the change.

Comment: Oh, man, I forgot about web browser cache. I just spent 10 minutes seeing why the `NE` condition didn't work. And then saw your edit at the bottom. Just curious though, how does browser cache affect it? `.htaccess` is interpreted on the server and the client browser has no notion of it.

Comment: If a clients browser gets `301` status from web server then it caches the original and redirected URLs locally. Next time you visit or enter original URL in browser it serves redirected URL and **skips** trip to web server.

Comment: Thanks. Just from curiosity, is there a shortcut to clear cache in Chrome just for one page? Akin to Shift+F5 for clearing CSS cache.

Comment: You can try `ctrl + R` together